# Extrair tags filhas de um XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Estou consumindo um servido da receita e ela me retorna um XML como por exemplo:

```
<retDistDFeInt xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.01" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
  <verAplic>1.1.9</verAplic>
  <cStat>138</cStat>
  <xMotivo>Documento(s) localizado(s)</xMotivo>
  <dhResp>2018-10-09T13:01:42-03:00</dhResp>
  <ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU>
  <maxNSU>000000000000013</maxNSU>
  <loteDistDFeInt>
    <docZip NSU="000000000000001" schema="resNFe_v1.01.xsd">XYZABCdUKAAF...etc</docZip>
    <docZip NSU="000000000000002" schema="resNFe_v1.01.xsd">XYZABCdUKAAF...ec</docZip>
  </loteDistDFeInt>
</retDistDFeInt>
```

Eu já tentei várias formas de extrair os valores das tags docZip do XML usando XElement com Linq e todas as vezes retornava vazio.

Alguns códigos que tentei:

```
var retorno = from nota in xmlRetorno.Elements("retDistDFeInt") select nota;

var retorno = from nota in xmlRetorno.Elements("loteDistDFeInt") select nota;

var points = xmlRetorno.Descendants("loteDistDFeInt");
var point = points.FirstOrDefault();

var retorno = from nota in xmlRetorno.Elements("loteDistDFeInt")
                          select new
                          {
                              nsu = (string)nota.Element("NSU"),
                              schema = (string)nota.Element("schema")
                          };
```

Comment: Raul, coloca o código do que já tentou fazer pra ajudarmos melhor

Comment: Coloquei alguns que lembrei que usei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está errado basicamente no seu código é o seguinte:

- não está usando *namespace* para navegar no `XElement`;
- está tratando atributo como elemento. "NSU" é um atributo no elemento "docZip".

Pode resolver assim:

```
XNamespace df = xmlRetorno.Name.Namespace;
var loteDistDFeIntElements = xmlRetorno.Element(df + "loteDistDFeInt").Elements();
var retorno = from nota in elements.Element(df + "loteDistDFeInt").Elements()
          select new
          {
              nsu = (string)nota.Attribute("NSU").Value,
              schema = (string)nota.Attribute("schema").Value
          };
```

Basicamente concatenei o namespace (variável **df**) para pesquisar o node "loteDistDFeInt" e extrai os elementos (`.Elements()`).
Depois li cada valor dos atributos "NSU" e "schema".

Aqui um fiddle demonstrando o funcionamento: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aruXTh

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.

```
var retorno = (from nota in xmlRetorno.Elements()
                           where nota.Name.LocalName.Equals("loteDistDFeInt")
                           select nota).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```